# Query Data Between Two Date from Date column in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to query data from btween two date from my date column.
I tested using api

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/expense?start=2019-08-01&2019-08-04`

but its give me all the records not from date range?

`My Controller`

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $user = auth()->user(); 

        $expenses = Expense::whereHas('user', function($subQuery) use($user){
            return $subQuery->where('shop_id', '=', $user->shop_id);
        })->with(['user'])->get();

        if($request->start && $request->end) {
            $expenses->where(function($q) use ($request) {
                $q->whereBetween('date', array($request->start, $request->end));
            });
        }

        return ExpenseResource::collection($expenses);

    }
```

i think i do something wrong with my Controller, but i cant still figure it out..

Thanks in advances...

Comment: try this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/expense?start=2019-08-01&end=2019-08-04

Comment: got this error `"explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"`

Comment: where did you using explode() function?

Comment: like u see in my controller, im not using it..

Comment: please check in `user` relation in `Expense` model. or did the error message returning any file name or line number?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran nope, it doesnt give any file or line.

Comment: check out my answer

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran are u still there? i have a bit issue want u to help?

Comment: Tell buddy. I ll be available 10 more minutes.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran i want to query data from between data using vuejs by click `btn` how can i archieve that?

Comment: sorry bro. I am not familiar with vuejs. I dont know how vuejs call web requests. I am using ajax call.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran its okay, bro now i solved it.

Comment: coooooooooooool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer helps

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $user = auth()->user(); 

    $expenses = Expense::whereHas('user', function($subQuery) use($user){
        return $subQuery->where('shop_id', '=', $user->shop_id);
    })->with(['user']);

    if($request->start && $request->end) {
        $expenses->whereBetween('date', array($request->start, $request->end));
    }        
    return ExpenseResource::collection($expenses->get());

}
```

what you did was you `get()` the result first then you apply `whereBetween()`.
Instead I applied `whereBetween()`  first then if your `if` condition satisfied the `get()`

and change your URL to 
`127.0.0.1:8000/api/expense?start=2019-08-01&end=2019-08-04`

Comment: suddenly, it got another error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()`

Comment: made some edit in answer. in  `if` clause. please try this one tooo

Comment: ok. made one more change in answer. `return ExpenseResource::collection($expenses->get());`

Comment: Thanks buddy. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$users = User::select("users.*")

            ->whereBetween('created', ['2018-02-01', '2018-02-10'])

            ->get();
```